# set LED light to android notification with firebase FCM

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase fcm to push notification to my android app.
I have two cases:

1. when the app in foreground: i receive the message in onMessageReceived method
2. when the app in background:  firebase push notification to my device ,so i want to add LED light to the notification,and i want to vibrate the device.

i use firebase cloud function

```
    request({
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' :' application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key='+"" },
    body: JSON.stringify({

      data: {
    title: 'Your app',
    message: "",
    body:""
  },to : ""})
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) { console.error(error); }

  });
```

Comment: Setting LED notifications are device specific. You can do these settings in your mobile's settings itself.

Comment: In my device i have other application that push notification with LED.But only my doesn't show light

Answer (score 0):

In the data portion of your FCM message:

```
 ledColor: [240, 0, 45, 1], //show a blinking LED in ARGB color format
```